# Flask Post method 405

Tags: python, html, flask

Why is Post method not being called i can use only get method

@Admin.route("/upload-image",methods=["GET", 'POST'])
def upload_image():

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    if request.files:
        pdf = request.files["pdf"]

        print(pdf)
        return redirect()
return '''<form action="/Admin/upload-image" method='POST'>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select PDF</label>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="pdf" id="pdf">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">Select PDF</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  </form>'''
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't seem relevant. Are you getting an error after sending a POST or are you not sure how to send a POST from a client?

Comment: First the Form is executed then we go to the upload_image() fun if the method is post then i do... or else if get is executed i return to the form again.the problem is that post method is never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a similar issue in my project and this is the solution I found :-)

Get call for login

```
@app.route("/login")
   def getCall():
     response = {}
     response['result'] = '0'
     response['messege'] = 'response from get'
     return response
```

post call for login

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def postCall():
 response = {}
 response['result'] = '0'
 response['messege'] = 'response from post'
 return response
```